# Does the Yuan-Ti playable race have legs or a snake tail?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits, yuan-ti

The [Yuan-Ti](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/1026407-yuan-ti) excerpt in *Monsters of the Multiverse* states (p. 36; emphasis my own):

> Blessed with resistance to magical and poisonous effects by the
> rituals that created them, **each of these yuan-ti manifests their
> serpentine heritage in a variety of ways:** a forked tongue, snake
> eyes, a snakelike nose, **or some other ophidian characteristic.**
> However a yuan-ti looks, they have the power to pursue great good or
> evil in the multiverse.

Does this suggest, RAW, that this variation of the Yuan-Ti might be either pure or half-blood? Could they appear as a Naga, or have serpentine hair like a Gorgon (Medusa)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm fairly certain the MotM Yuan-ti is intended to still be a pureblood; they just left off the "pureblood" part of the name (it was always a confusing name from the get-go). As such, major modifications like replacing legs with a tail for locomotion are beyond what is intended.

Evidence includes:

- The MotM description quoted, while allowing for other ophidian characteristics, uses a bunch of fairly subtle ones that make no major changes to the humanoid body plan as examples; if they intended to allow gross body plan changes, you'd expect at least one such example.
- The Yuan-ti PC race remains type Humanoid. **Across the *Monster Manual* and MotM, the *only* Yuan-ti monster that is of type Humanoid rather than Monstrosity is the *Monster Manual*'s Yuan-ti Pureblood.** Non-pureblood yuan-ti are Monstrosities; therefore, the PC race is almost certainly pureblood.
- While nothing in the rules strictly defines the full set of features that make someone "humanoid":

  1. **The *Monster Manual* definition of "humanoid" specifies that they are bipedal** (which means two legs with feet or feet-equivalents like hooves, no replacing them with a snake tail) (emphasis added):

     > Humanoids are the main peoples of the D&D world, both civilized and savage, including humans and a tremendous variety of other species. They have language and culture, few if any innate magical abilities (though most humanoids can learn spellcasting), **and a bipedal form.**
  2. Even if it didn't, the plain English definition implies a body plan largely similar to that of a human. The greatest deviation from that I can find is aarakocra and lizardfolk, both of which merely *add* to the basic humanoid body plan (adding two wings or a tail respectively to the basic humanoid body plan of two arms, two legs, one head, and the fact that aarakocra wings don't double as arms is new to 5E IIRC, and for all we know, a mistake on the part of the artist); replacing legs with a snake tail for locomotion is a more significant divergence from a humanoid body plan.

Comment: Re: “nothing in the rules defines humanoid”, that’s not quite true, the intro to the MM defines it for us:  “Humanoids are the main peoples of the D&D world, both civilized and savage, including humans and a tremendous variety of other species. They have language and culture, few if any innate magical abilities (though most humanoids can learn spellcasting), and a bipedal form.”

Comment: @ThomasMarkov: Ah, it does actually say "bipedal" (I missed that). The rest of it has nothing to do with body plan though. I'll note the bipedal part though.

Comment: Yeah, “bipedal” is the only morphological observation made, everything else is sociological.

Comment: *"aarakocra ... for all we know, a mistake on the part of the artist"* - maybe the *first* aarakocra artwork for 5e. But it's been replicated that way for every 5e image that I've seen. That's how they are now.

Comment: @Adeptus: Yeah, don't mind me over here, remembering 2E Dark Sun aarakocra and thinking the new ones are frankly a little boring for becoming ever less bird-like. :-)

Answer (score 7):

It seems unlikely the writer would mention three minor cosmetic characteristics if the intent was to be able to totally change your character's body-plan. Equally, it seems unlikely that a change that dramatic could pass with no mechanical modifications whatsoever.

The given examples of 'snake-like characteristics' match with how the *Monster Manual* (p. 310) describes the (unfortunately named) [yuan-ti pureblood](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/monsters-y#YuantiPureblood):

> [...] a pureblood can't pass for human under close scrutiny because there's always some hint of its true nature, such as scaly patches of skin, serpentine eyes, pointed teeth, or a forked tongue.

Still, that said, if you and your DM want to go wild with this, that's up to you to figure out. Just keep in mind that "I have a snakelike lower body" is a dramatic change that will require on-the-fly rulings and may have other rules implications - some minor, such as the inability to wear boots or pants, and some serious, like potentially applying the Centaur difficulty with climbing under some circumstances.

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify? Snakes can climb trees just fine, and can even swim with quite the agility. So other than adding a few extra features ( like a climbing speed), I see it no different than a minotaur or satyr...

Comment: Snakes can climb as long as they have something to push off against, but a snake the size of a man wouldn't be able to climb the way a creature with toes could. In any case, the point I'm making is that if you want to do this and the DM allows it, it's fine, but be prepared for surprise rulings.

Comment: Will prepare a contingency, however, I'd like to note that large snakes like anacondas and pythons can also climb using a combination of finding ledges and using one muscle to push up the other. with that feat, things like this are possible: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pNhyRsBLNZQ A human-sized snake would be able to climb.. at least as good as a human could.

Comment: As a proud snake owner I strongly disagree with climb difficulty increase.  A lot of snskes can climb like you wouldn't believe. And not only arboreal or semi-arboreal ones.

Comment: I would like to submit this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TIPgJY4wJvU for the climbing discussion. :)

Comment: For what it's worth, what I was really thinking of here was the kind of climbing where you're wedging fingers and toes into crevices to get a grip. I have no real doubt a yuan-ti with a snake-body can climb a tree or a surface with projections, but in some cases the lack of toes will be a real difficulty. But I don't really want to sidetrack into a debate about how snakes climb. It was just an example.

Answer (score 3):

### Yuan-Ti range from almost entirely snake-like to almost entirely humanoid.

In a *colossally bone-headed* move, Wizards of the Coast declared *Volo’s Guide to Monsters* obsolete, and replaced it with the *woefully deficient* in lore *Monsters of the Multiverse*. Luckily, *Volo’s Guide* answers your question in the section ["Yuan-ti: Snake People"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/vgtm/monster-lore#YuantiSnakePeople) (p. 92):

> [...] Ages ago their dark gods taught them profane, cannibalistic rituals to mix their flesh with that of snakes, producing a caste-based society of hybrids in which the most snakelike are the leaders and the most humanlike are spies and agents in foreign lands.
>
> [...]
>
> The bodies of all yuan-ti have a mix of humanlike and snakelike parts, but the proportion varies from individual to individual. After the initial metamorphosis of the humans, their society quickly coalesced into a caste system based on how complete a person’s transformation was. The vast majority of yuan-ti fall into three categories — abominations, malisons, and purebloods — while the mutated broodguards and exceedingly rare anathemas have their place in the hierarchy as well.

...with further details and pictures contained therein.

Canonically, there is a pretty broad range for Yuan-Ti, from very snake-like to very human-like. Just ask your DM if your idea for your character is setting appropriate.

Comment: I assume they deprecated Volo's primarily because it plays into the whole "evil races that are inherently evil" thing pretty hard, and one of the explicit goals of MotM was to move away from the implication that evil is a genetic quality carried by certain races of people.

Comment: Yes, however, the only playable race in Volo's Guide was the Yuan-Ti Pureblood, with some other more perfected forms even gaining the ability to turn into giant snakes. As far as I know, those other types could not be used as a playable race and I am wondering if MotM changed that.

Comment: @VictorB That isn't really the question you initially asked. That said... one of the thing's that's missing from the modern printings of the lore is that "pureblood" is an insult among Yuan-Ti. The more purely-human one appears, the *lesser* one is considered in Yuan-Ti society.